# Modify FindAll function to a DoesExist function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-function

I have the following recursive function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ListAncestors] 
(   
    @Id int
)   
RETURNS TABLE  
As  
RETURN  
(   
    WITH cte As  
    (   
        SELECT
            UserId,
            ManagerId,  
            Forename,
            Surname  
        FROM  
            dbo.Users   
        WHERE  
            UserId = @Id   

        UNION ALL  

        SELECT  
            T.UserID,
            T.ManagerID,  
            T.Forename,   
            T.Surname  
        FROM  
            cte As C INNER JOIN dbo.Users As T   
            ON C.UserID = T.ManagerID   
    )   
    SELECT
        Forename,
   Surname 
    FROM  
        cte
);
```

Basically what it does is returns the names of all users below the specified user (based on their ID). What I would like to do is modify this function and create another function which does a check if a specific userID is an ancestor of another.

I imagine the signature would look something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsAncestor(@Id int, @AncestorId int) RETURNS BIT
```

Comment: Are you aware of HeirarchyID in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: @Mitch: Using SQL Server 2005. Tagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
WHILE @Id IS NOT NULL AND @Id <> @AncestorId
BEGIN
 SET @Id = (
  SELECT ManagerId FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserId = @Id
 )
END

RETURN CASE WHEN @Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, I queried `select * from Users where dbo.IsAncestor(UserID, ASpecificUserID) = 1` which I would have expected to return me everyone above the specific user but it only returned me the specific user themselves.

Comment: Hmm - odd - have you tried running the query outside of the scope of a function to see how it behaves?

Comment: Apologies I was misusing the function. This does actually work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If we accept that the initial CTE takes an ID and lists all the 'ancestors' of that ID, I think that the following query tests for this relation.

```
WITH cte As  
(   
    SELECT
        UserId,
        Forename,
        Surname  
    FROM  
        dbo.Users   
    WHERE  
        UserId = @Id   

    UNION ALL  

    SELECT  
        T.UserID,  
        T.Forename,   
        T.Surname  
    FROM  
        cte As C INNER JOIN dbo.Users As T   
        ON C.UserID = T.ManagerID and C.UserID <> @ancestorID
)   
SELECT CAST (COUNT(*) as BIT) FROM cte WHERE UserID = @ancestorID
```

It's a bit odd though, since given the initial function a person is in the 'ancestor' relation with themselves.

Incidentally, I removed the ManagerID from the select statements in the CTE since it isn't necessary

Comment: @Yellowfrog: Yeah I was still in the middle of tweaking the initial method. I have removed the instance of the person themselves.

Comment: So there is no way of dropping out early? You need to run the initial functional all the time anyway?